# Trying to print name of all csv files within a given folder

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in python that loops through data from various csv files within a folder. Right now I just want to see that the program can identify the files in a folder but I am unable to have my code print the file names in my folder. This is what I have so far, and I'm not sure what my problem is. Could it be the periods in the folder names in the file path?

```
import glob

path = "Users/Sarah/Documents/College/Lab/SEM EDS/1.28.20 CZTS hexane/*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print fname
```

No error messages are popping up but nothing will print. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the lack of indentation intentional under your for loop ?

Comment: Should there be a leading `/` in the path?

Comment: To expand on the comment by @wobr, `path` as it currently stands is a relative path. This could be correct, if the directory you are running the code from has a `Users/Sarah/...` directory path. Putting a leading `/` will use a path that starts from the root directory, no matter where the script is run from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a Linux-base system ? If you're not, switch the `/` for `\\`.

Is the directory you're giving the full path, from the root folder ? You might need to 
specify a FULL path (drive included).

If that still fails, silly but check there actually are files in there, as your code otherwise seems fine.

This code below worked for me, and listed csv files appropriately (see the `C:\\` part, could be what you're missing).

```
import glob

path = "C:\\Users\\xhattam\\Downloads\\TEST_FOLDER\\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding the / at the start of the path fixed the problem

Comment: Awesome ! Please close the question if your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code gets a list of files in a folder and if they have csv in them it will print the file name.

```
import os

path = r"C:\temp"

filesfolders = os.listdir(path)

for file in filesfolders:
    if ".csv" in file:
        print (file)
```

Note the indentation in my code. You need to be careful not to mix tabs and spaces as theses are not the same to python.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `os`

```
import os
files_list = os.listdir(path)
out_list = []
for item in files_list:
    if item[-4:] == ".csv":
        out_list.append(item)
print(out_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the correct path?
Try moving the python script in the folder when the CSV files are, and then change it to this:

```
import glob

path = "./*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print fname
```